# How to pick a particular package based on a particular table column value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apps

I have a situation here:

We need to run  `procedure_1` in a package when a particular column say column `X` has data in it and simultaneously run another `procedure_2` in package if there is no data in that column `X`

Can anyone please advice on what can be done using Oracle ?

Comment: Could you provide some more details - what have you tried that isn't working? Can you show some example code, and what you'd want the output to look like?

Comment: @kfinity I'm looking for a package which can have two different procedure doing some operations but those operations must be done based on certain validation i.e., a column from table having can either have values or cannot have values i.e., null. So, if the table is having null as column value it must run procedure 1 or else procedure 2.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

- table `DECIDE` contains `PARTICULAR_COLUMN`
- package has two simple procedures which do nothing; they just *identify* themselves

.

```
SQL> create table decide
  2    (id                number,
  3     particular_column varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into decide values (1, 'X');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into decide values (2, null);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace package pkg_decide as
  2    procedure p1;
  3    procedure p2;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_decide as
  2    procedure p1 is
  3    begin
  4      dbms_output.put_line('-> running proc 1');
  5    end;
  6
  7    procedure p2 is
  8    begin
  9      dbms_output.put_line('-> running proc 2');
 10    end;
 11  end;
 12  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Testing: if the `PARTICULAR_COLUMN` isn't empty, `P1` will run; otherwise, `P2`. That can be done with dynamic SQL, i.e. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. As we're going to run a procedure, we have to form a full anonymous PL/SQL block (begin - procedure name - end).

P.S. As suggested by Matthew, a simple IF will do.

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select particular_column,
  3                         case when particular_column is not null then 'pkg_decide.p1'
  4                             else 'pkg_decide.p2'
  5                         end prc_name
  6                  from decide
  7                 ) loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line('particular column = ' || cur_r.particular_column ||
  9                           ', should run procedure ' || cur_r.prc_name);
 10      execute immediate 'begin ' ||cur_r.prc_name ||'; end;';
 11
 12      -- Or, as suggested by Matthew, a simple IF will do
 13      if cur_r.particular_column is not null then
 14         pkg_decide.p1;
 15      else
 16         pkg_decide.p2;
 17      end if;
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
particular column = X, should run procedure pkg_decide.p1
-> running proc 1
-> running proc 1
particular column = , should run procedure pkg_decide.p2
-> running proc 2
-> running proc 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Why not just `IF particular_column IS NOT NULL THEN pkg_decide.p1; ELSE pkg_decide.pk2; END IF;`?  That is, why the dynamic SQL?

Comment: Huh, @Matthew, because - when I saw the question, the first *image* that blinked in front of my eyes was *dynamic SQL*. By all means, your suggestion is just fine. I'll add it to that code.

Comment: Hey @MatthewMcPeak I'm trying to have the validation for column having null value or not to  be included inside a package which has two procedures.

Comment: @NerdFredrick That's not a very clear statement and you provided no sample code or sample data or expected results.  As I interpret your vague question, Littlefoot's answer is the one.